# Why the path of my file is not correct when I trying to create database?

Tags: sql-server

I just started learning SQL. I downloaded the mdf file and moved it to the SQL folder. The course instructor told us to enter these commands to display the finished database. It throws me the error that my file doesn't exist even though I entered the correct path name. What is the matter? Sorry if the question is too stupid I just started learning.
Here is some pictures of the problem.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message shows the file path is missing the backslash after the folder name. Perhaps the value in the query window was copy/pasted and includes non-displayable control characters. I suggest you open a new query window, type the statement from scratch, and run the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your .mdf file should be in this path:

```
FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQL\SQLData\<database name>.mdf'
```

To attach a database there are some ways to do it like :

1. The one i've showed you:

   ```
   USE [master]
   GO
   create database <DatabaseName> ON
   (name='LogicalName of the Data file', FileName='Data File Name'),
   (name='LogicalName of the Log file', FileName='Log File Name')
   FOR ATTACH;
   ```
2. Or this way:

   ```
   USE [master]
   GO
   EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'DatabaseName',   
       @filename1 =   '<Location of the database file>',   
       @filename2 =   '<Location of the Log file>';
   ```